# I Dropped my nikon D3300

Tags: nikon, nikon-d3300, overexposure, exposure-correction

A few days ago I dropped my Nikon D3300. I then found it is taking overexposed images while all the settings are correct. The meter in manual mode misguides me even in daylight. At ISO 100, f/5.6 it says to keep shutter at 1/160 to get proper image and providing wrong info. A question mark in the viewfinder always says lightning is poor. I have to move exposure compensation to -2.7 to -3.0 to get a perfect shot.

When I switch to Live View it does not do that. Now the meter works correctly and gives proper info. There is no problem with lens. I tried this with couple of lens and it works. What to do? Please help.

Comment: I'm not sure what anyone could really say except take it to a repair shop & see if the cost of repair doesn't outweigh the cost of replacement.

Comment: Can you see, if the aperture is actually moving? It sounds like a stuck aperture.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the mirror assembly is damaged, leading to incorrect light meter readings. In an SLR, the light metering sensor is contained in the viewfinder that gets its light via the mirror. The autofocus sensor gets its light via the secondary mirror. If you dislodged the mirror or the metering sensor when you dropped it, that could explain what you are seeing.

The reason your camera meters correctly in Live View is that the metering sensor in the viewfinder is not used in Live View. Instead, the camera reads the main sensor to do metering.

I see that a used D3300 goes for about $150, so you might be better off buying a replacement vs. sending it in for repair (which will likely cost at least $150). Might be time to upgrade, depending on how much you can spend.